# Based on screen size, Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my conf file I am setting my browser window to be maximized in onPrepare{},

I am seeing an odd behavior, When I run the test on my 15inch Mac screen, I get:

Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11004ms.

But if I run the same test and drag my browser to a bigger monitor, the test passes.

Comment: What Protractor version are you using?